# `[Worker Messenger] [Page -> SW] Could not get ServiceWorkerRegistration to postMessage

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, service-worker, onesignal, postmessage

`[Worker Messenger] [Page -> SW] Could not get ServiceWorkerRegistration to postMessage!
I am getting this error in Chrome, and the same code is working fine for edge
It's not been working last few days
I want to print this information
I am getting this error in Chrome, and the same code is working fine for edge
It's not been working last few days

```
OneSignalSDKWorker.js
importScripts("https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDKWorker.js");
Index.tsx
OneSignal.init({
  appId: "oneSignalAppid",
  autoRegister: true,
  persistNotification: true,
  notificationClickHandlerMatch: "URL",
});
App.tsx
 useEffect(() => {
    const onNotificationClicked = function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    };
    const handler = function (data) {
      onNotificationClicked(data);
    };
    OneSignal.addListenerForNotificationOpened(handler);
    OneSignal.getUserId().then(function (userId) {
      setUserID(userId);
    });
    // Handle received notifications
    OneSignal.on("notificationDisplay", (event) => {
      console.log(event);
    });
  }, []);
```